# What is the formula of operating voltage of GM counter?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, particle-detectors

In some manuals I found operating voltage formula $$V=V_1+(1/3)(V_2-V_1)$$ and in other manuals $$V=(V_2+V_1)/2.$$ Which formula is correct? If both are correct, then please give the reason.

Comment: The correct one is the formula in the manual for your particular instrument.

Comment: Please define your notation for us.

Comment: Or $(2V_1+V_2)/3$. Or just somewhere on the plateau.